# move dom element position relative to client screen

Tags: javascript

I need to move some Dom element relative to user screen or window not parent element, but I didn't find any solution.

I know there is a way in jQuery plugin but I need do it with pure javascript

Comment: use CSS `position: fixed;`

Comment: Please elaborate, does the element have to be fixed on the screen? Does it need to move around on scroll, or resize. What have you tried so far?

Comment: it is for a plugin and it's may be used by absolute position. I need to force element to move into some direction relative to document or window

Comment: PS: ***screen*** is not ***browser viewport***!

Comment: Please edit your question providing as much detail so we can imagine what exactly you're after. Don't expect others to put time into writing aa detailed answer if you don't put time into writing a clear question. So please, provide more details. Your question will otherwise get closed as it's hard to imagine your specific problem. Describe in words, maybe even use images if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

[**CSS** `position: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```css
#myElement {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10vw;
  top: 10vh;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

Or using **JavaScript** [CSSStyleDeclaration cssText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/cssText):

```js
const myEl = document.querySelector("#myElement");
myEl.style.cssText = `
  position: fixed;
  left: 10vw;
  top: 10vh;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
`;
```

but I don't see why would you use JS for that task.

Notice that **screen** and the browser **viewport** are not the same in development. Screen is the physical screen. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenX if that might interest you in some other calculations about where the browser viewport is in relation to the screen